# How do I present the data for different time periods in a non redundant way?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a query where I'm presenting data for every time period  The query has become redundant and it became so hard as I have more categories.

## Query

```
select 'MISC' as Label, 'MISC 12 months' as Label, min(created_at), count(*) FROM services
```

Comment: Can you please add an example set of data and the result you want? Since we don't know your tables structure and data. It would be easier to help if you provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run this small query as it should assist your understanding of the suggestion to follow. Basically it is just a list of intervals, which we can then use to create a set of dates.

```
WITH Ranges as (
     select '1 day' as duration union all
     select '1 month' as duration union all
     select '1 week' as duration union all
     select '2 months' as duration union all
     select '3 months' as duration union all
     select '4 months' as duration union all
     select '5 months' as duration union all
     select '6 months' as duration union all
     select '12 months' as duration
    )
select current_date - r.duration::interval
from ranges r
;
```

So, we use that table of intervals as both a label and an interval, via a `CROSS JOIN` on your services table (so we get one services row for each interval), and then we use "conditional aggregates" (case expressions inside the aggregate functions) to arrive at the wanted results. You can add or remove new intervals into the common table expression, OR (optionally) you could create a real table if you need these to be common over many queries.

```
WITH Ranges as (
     select '1 day' as duration union all
     select '1 month' as duration union all
     select '1 week' as duration union all
     select '2 months' as duration union all
     select '3 months' as duration union all
     select '4 months' as duration union all
     select '5 months' as duration union all
     select '6 months' as duration union all
     select '12 months' as duration
    )
select
    , concat('MISC ',r.duration) as Label
    , current_date - r.duration::interval as dt_from
    , min(case when created_at > current_date - r.duration::interval then created_at end) as min_created_at
    , count(case when created_at > current_date - r.duration::interval then created_at end) as count_of
from services
cross JOIN Ranges r
group by
      r.duration
```

I have no opportunity to test the lower query so please excuse any errors in that.

Comment: cross apply syntax error. I have read-only permissions to the db.

Comment: Im sorry that should have been `cross join` i have edited the code above too.